# How to Display Numbers in the Form(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13)

Tags: c#, console-application

How to Display Numbers in the Form(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13) 
Such that the number first 1 number is displayed then second is the number with addition of previous 
=>
0 then 1 then 1+0 = 1then 1+1= 2 then 1+2=3 and so on?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i) ;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();             
        }
    }
}
```

Suggest some code please

Comment: Are you asking how to compute [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)?

Answer (score 5):

*Decompose* your solution into Fibonacci sequence generator:

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Linq;

public static IEnumerable<BigInteger> Fibonacci() {
  BigInteger a = 0;
  BigInteger b = 1;

  yield return a;
  yield return b;

  while (true) {
    BigInteger result = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = result;

    yield return result;
  }
}
```

And sequence representation:

```
  Console.Write(String.Join(" ", Fibonacci().Take(20)));
```

Comment: Great use of `BigInteger`, `yield` and `Take()` to let OP's homework definitely look like they copied it from the web. But really, you shouldn't answer questions like this one. How to calculate Fibonacci numbers in C# can be found in thousands of places on the web, there definitely are duplicates on Stack Overflow, and OP's question is very unclear (for _what_ help they're actually looking for).

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. I wouldn't recommend handing this in to your teacher, though:

```
double Phi = (1.0 + Math.Sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;
double D = 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(5.0);

Func<int, ulong> fib = i => (ulong) ((Math.Pow(Phi, i) - Math.Pow(1.0 - Phi, i))*D);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(0, 21).Select(i => fib(i))));
```

(In seriousness, I just posted this to demonstrate that there is an analytic solution to fibonnaci, as well as the normal iterative one. This only works up to n == 71, though.)

Comment: Technically, `(long) (Math.Pow(Phi, i)*D + 0.5)` fill be a faster solution ;) a possible flaw with your code is that *truncating* `double` to `long` can cause round up errors.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It only works up to n == 71. Of course, I didn't invent the code. ;)